# How to add a method to the versions model of Paper_trail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create the following method for paper_trail versions:

```
def user
  User.find self.whodunnit.to_i
end
```

So that I can access a version's user naturally in my app as if it has a `belongs_to` relation.

**Where should I put this function (folder and file name) in order to override / add it to paper_trail's version model?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put this in an initializer (e.g., `config/initializers/paper_trail.rb`) that opens the `PaperTrail::Version` class:

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    def user
      User.find self.whodunnit.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

You'll want to confirm that your `Version` model is `PaperTrail::Version`; older versions of the gem use just `Version`. In that case, just remove the outer module statement.

You could also create a custom class inheriting from `Version`, and specify that in your `has_paper_trail` call. For example (from the README):

```
class PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  # custom behaviour, e.g:
  self.table_name = :post_versions
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :class_name => 'PostVersion'
end
```

Comment: For anyone trying this now: from version 3.0.3 onwards, you need to include the following line at the top of config/initializers/paper_trail.rb:

`PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!`

References: [full code in readme](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#storing-metadata), [Github issue](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/392).